# How to fix sizing problem in color picker when i change language to arabic

Tags: android-studio, arabic, color-picker

I am setting color picker dialog to application when the language is English it's working without problem 
but when I change language to Arabic it seems like that

a screen shot to the problem :

[image]
Here is my code :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        mDefaultColor = ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openColorPicker();
            }
        });
    }


///
    public void openColorPicker() {
        AmbilWarnaDialog colorPicker = new AmbilWarnaDialog(this, mDefaultColor, new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
                mDefaultColor = color;
                mLayout.setBackgroundColor(mDefaultColor);
            }
        });
        colorPicker.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have same issue. Have you find its solution?